# replacing socket.io with telepat for real time updates

Tags: websocket, socket.io, real-time, telepat

How does telepat-io differ from socket-io and other socket based real time sytems ? what is the underlying technology - is it a wrapper on top of socket-io ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through [their website](http://telepat.io/#design), you can see references to `socket.io`...

Reading through their code, for example, their [client code](https://github.com/telepat-io/telepat-js/blob/eb78aa3115ec062b58538d6f84c7972f32d7ed37/package.json), you can also find references to `socket.io`...

It seems to me that the word `wrapper` doesn't fit, as they focus on creating an optimized design for meshing different technologies to create a real-time application backend... I would go with the word `framework` if I had to put a name on it. If you like their approach, you'll probably enjoy simplified scaling as this is one of their main concerns.

Answer (score 1):

As Myst pointed out, Telepat is more of a framework, a full stack software. This framework uses socket.io for the notification part of the system: clients manipulate application resources -> API -> workers -> subscribed clients get notified of the changes through various means (Apple Push Notifications, Google Cloud Messaging and web sockets for any other client).

So in short: Telepat uses socket.io for client notifications.